# Storing key using KeyStore in Android

Tags: java, android, exception, keystore, fileoutputstream

I am using KeyStore to protect my private key but when the line:

```
FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput("bs.keystore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

is executed I have this exception:

```
'java.lang.NullPointerException'.
```

I don't understand where is the problem.

Code:

```
    private Context ctx;

    public DataSec(Context ctx) 
    {
    ctx = this.ctx;
    }

    public void genKey() throws Exception
    {
    SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null, "clavedekey".toCharArray());

    PasswordProtection pass = new PasswordProtection("fedsgjk".toCharArray());
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(key);
    ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, pass);

    FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput("bs.keystore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ks.store(fos, "clavedekey".toCharArray());
    fos.close();        
    }
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
public DataSec(Context ctx) 
{
ctx = this.ctx;
}
```

To

```
public DataSec(Context ctx) 
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

Right now, you're assigning the context parameter in the method to the same value as the global one, which is null. Due to this, your context doesn't actually get stored.

Comment: I lost more than one hour in this problem. I really feel very fool. Thanks!

Comment: That is why you should use final keyword on method parameters.

Comment: hello Raghav how do we came to know that our key are saved means is there any way to retrive the key from keystore.?