# Android store byte[] in the keystore

Tags: android, key, keystore

I'm very confused about the keystore. 
I found a lot threads about it but nothing works. I want to store and load a specified key (byte[] and not generated) in the keystore. 
Is that working? I tried a lot but nothing works.

Do you have some codesnippets?

THANKS
Jules

Edit:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);
ks.setEntry(alias, entry, param);
OutputStream writeStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
ks.store(writeStream, passwordForKey);
writeStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Bas64-Encoding (Android.util.Base64) to store it as a string.
There is no function to store a raw byte-Array

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
I changed the question with a codesnippet, is it working in that way?

Comment: Together with your answer and this thread it's working now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972316/storing-key-using-keystore-in-android?rq=1
THANKS!!!