# Is possible to put own key to AndroidKeyStore?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, key, android-keystore

I am thinking about this question:

Is possible to put my own key to `AndroidKeyStore` and using it for other operations (signing some text/docs)?

I have generated a `PostQuantum` keys (priv/pub) for signing algorithm `SPHINCS`, that includes `BouncyCastle` library.

Is there some ways, how to initialize my plan?

Thank you for your hints :)

There is an example code, how I am generating a priv/pub keys by **BouncyCastle SPHINCS**:

```
SPHINCS256KeyPairGenerator generator = new SPHINCS256KeyPairGenerator();
generator.init(new SPHINCS256KeyGenerationParameters(new RiggedRandom(), new SHA3Digest(256)));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = generator.generateKeyPair();

SPHINCSPrivateKeyParameters priv = (SPHINCSPrivateKeyParameters)kp.getPrivate();
SPHINCSPublicKeyParameters pub = (SPHINCSPublicKeyParameters)kp.getPublic();
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible now. Android Keystore is more than just a storage for keys, it also performs all the crypto operations that use that key. Thus Android Keystore needs to support your post-quantum algorithms and, unfortunately, it currently does not.

Comment: And what about to save PQ key as byte array to AndroidKeyStore?

Something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753025/android-store-byte-in-the-keystore

Comment: Possibly, but what would be the point? You could never do anything with byte array once it's imported into the Android Keystore.

Comment: I think, that I can export back mentoined byte array (the key) and set it to type SPHINCSPrivateKeyParameters if I will want to work with that.

Comment: You can't export keys out of Android Keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this(Sample for Andorid M(6.0)+ )

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private void initGeneratorWithKeyGenParameterSpec() {
            try {
                KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ALGORITHM", "AndroidKeyStore");
                String alias = "myAlias";
                Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                endDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 20);
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT|KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                        .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                        .setCertificateNotBefore(startDate.getTime())
                        .setCertificateNotAfter(endDate.getTime())
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                        .setKeySize(2048)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1);
                generator.initialize(builder.build());
                generator.generateKeyPair();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLogger.logException(Logger.Level.ERROR, Logger.Category.ENCRYPTION, "KeyStoreWrapper", "initGeneratorWithKeyGenParameterSpec()", e);
            }
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the way. KeyPairGenerator can getInstance from pre-defined algorithms in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyPairGenerator

Comment: Maybe I can try to save some bytes to AndroidKeyStore for example as there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753025/android-store-byte-in-the-keystore